# VBA 2010 Increment Range row count won't increment

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create borders for my spreadsheet and do a comparison of two values. To do this I must increment the row in my range but the formula I am using won't increment.

```
Set ws = Sheets(strSheetName)
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Stop
'Create borders
  For Each c In Range("A1:A" & lRow)
      If Trim(c.Value) = PracticeName Then First = "A" & c.Row
      If Trim(c.Value) = "SubTotal" Then SubTotal = "B" & c.Row
      If Trim(c.Value) = "" Then
         Set Rng = Sheets(strSheetName).Range(First & ":" & SubTotal)
         Call SetRangeBorder(Rng)
      End If
    If Trim(c.Value) = PracticeName Then FirstDataRow = "B" & c.Row + 2
    If Trim(c.Value) = "IDX" Then LastDataRow = "B" & c.Row
    Stop
    If LastDataRow <> "" And SubTotal <> "" Then
        If Trim(c.Value) = "SubTotal" Then Range(SubTotal).Formula = "=SUM(" 
     & FirstDataRow & ":" & LastDataRow & ")"
        'Check if Values are equal
        Stop
        compare1 = Range(SubTotal)
        FinalRow = "B" & c.Row + 1
        compare2 = Range(FinalRow)
        'If equal set color to green
        If compare1 = compare2 Then Range(FinalRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        'If not equal set color to red
        If compare1 <> compare2 Then Range(FinalRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Range("A" & c.Row) = Range("A" & c.Row).Offset(3, 0)
         Stop
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Also make sure to add the worksheet before `Range("A1:A" & lRow)` to make sure you're running that on the right one...I assume it's `ws.Range("A1:A" & lRow)`?

Comment: How did you declare `c` (Data Type)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead and it will work:

```
For i = 1 to lRow
```

And when referencing cells you'd use:

```
ws.Cells(i,1).Value
```

The "i" is the row number, and the "1" is the column number. This will increment the row in whichever column you want. This method is just preference and feels easier to visualize for me.